# How can I optimise the below VBA/Excel code?

Tags: vba

I am trying to do a multiple vlookup in a single cell. But the current code is very slow and takes a lot of time. Can anyone suggest how to optimise this code?

Example

```
Apples  A
B
C
Oranges D
```

Expected Result

```
Apples A B C
```

My code

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xResult As String
    xResult = ""
    For Each rng In pWorkRng
        If rng = pValue Then
            xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
        End If
    Next
    MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function
```

No error but I am expecting the vlookup to be performed faster with the values in a single cell

Comment: The excel format is not captured properly. So explaining again - Column A1 has Apples and A4 has Oranges. B1, B2, B3 have the values as Ant, Bat, Cat. B4 has D. In A5 if I type Apples, the code should give the result as Ant Bat Cat

Comment: Does your current code produces what you are expecting? As far as I can tell, it doesn't, be that slow or not.

Comment: Hi darxyde. Yes it does give the correct result. If you are able to suggest an alternate code that would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: So, this part of your code `If rng = pValue Then` is checking that if your `pValue` (`Apples`) is equal to any cell in `pWorkRng` (`Ant or Bat or Cat`), then add them together. Quite obviously this values are not equal, hence it can't be working as you explained, or expecting it too. From my view, this will only ever return a value if `pValue` = `rng`. Please add a screenshot with values you are using this function against, the expected result, and the formula you are using to call the function. I can then try to guess what you are trying to achieve and help you out.